# Can't find PyInstaller when installing through pip on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to install PyInstaller.

I went to my command prompt and types in:

```
python -m pip install PyInstaller
```

After doing a few retry's it gives me the message
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Xukrao.

The ping did not work so as you suggested I spoke to our IT guy who knew right away that it was a proxy issue and needed to input something like below to get it working.

```
[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port
```

Answer (score 0):

The impression that I get from your error message is that the issue is not specific to PyInstaller, but rather that there's a general issue connecting to the Python Package Index server.

I would advise to double check that your machine is able to connect to the `pypi.python.org` domain (e.g. do a simple ping test).

Comment: Thanks for your response Xukrao, sorry it took me a while to get back went on holidays a few days after posting this. I haven't been back to the office yet, but just tried the install on my home computer and it works fine. So two questions: How do I do a ping test like that and how would I go about fixing it if the test fails? Thanks

Comment: To do a ping test, type `ping pypi.python.org` into a command prompt. If it fails at the office, then it can be for a wide variety of reasons. So you're probably best of asking your company's IT service for help at that point.